# How to use jquery to insert html in same class name different data-id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I am facing a simple issue being new to jquery. I have a condition where there is the same class but different className. Now I need to show one html when data-id is true and another html when data-id is false. My code is:

```
<div class="emailSent" data-id="True"></div>
<div class="emailSent" data-id="False"></div>
<div class="emailSent" data-id="False"></div>
```

My jquery Code is :

```
if ($(".emailSent").attr("data-id") == "True") {
  $(".emailSent").html("&#10004;&#65039;")
} else {
  $(".emailSent").html("&#10060;")
}
```

While trying the above code I am always getting the html for first div.
How can i do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/u1j9hatc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `loop` through `class` because there is multiple `class` with same name

```js
$('.emailSent').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('id') == "True"){
        $(this).html("&#10004;&#65039;");
    } else {
        $(this).html("&#10060;");
    }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="emailSent" data-id="True"></div>
<div class="emailSent" data-id="False"></div>
<div class="emailSent" data-id="False"></div>
```

Comment: Using each seems to be too much for such a simple task when we could just do it in two lines, much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

`$(".emailSent")` is returning multiple elements (3), which have the class emailSent.

You need to loop through them using `.each()`

More info: https://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to set a red cross on false div and a green checkmark on true ?

Then you could simply select those classes while using a data-id selector and do this :

```
$(".emailSent[data-id='False']").html("&#10060;")
$(".emailSent[data-id='True']").html("&#10004;&#65039;")
```

Here, we select all emailSend classes with data-id='False' or 'True' and change their html content.

We could loop through each .emailSent and do something like this, but since jQuery modify the html for EACH element selected, it's way more simple to do it like this.

You can try it: https://jsfiddle.net/mxyapL4r/